# How use array in Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have initializated array in Angular JS:

```
$scope.formData.universitySelected = [];
```

I try to fill array in loop:

```
 angular.forEach($scope.formData.university, function (value, key) {
    if (typeof value === 'object') {
         $scope.formData.universitySelected[key].id = value.IdEducation;
    } else {
        $scope.formData.universitySelected[key].selected = value;
    }
});
```

But I get error:

> Cannot set property 'id' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to define that object first then add value to in it.

**Code**

```
angular.forEach($scope.formData.university, function (value, key) {
    if (typeof value === 'object') {
         $scope.formData.universitySelected[key] = {id : value.IdEducation};
    } else {
        $scope.formData.universitySelected[key] = {selected : value.IdEducation};
    }
});
```

Comment: If `$scope.formData.universitySelected[key]` already exists, your code will remove any other properties.

Comment: @RobinJamesKerrison yes I know..before editing my answer..@hansmaad already added his answer..

Answer (score 2):

You should create an object before using it.

```
angular.forEach($scope.formData.university, function (value, key) {
   $scope.formData.universitySelected[key] = $scope.formData.universitySelected[key] || {};
   if (typeof value === 'object') {
      $scope.formData.universitySelected[key].id = value.IdEducation;
   } else {
      $scope.formData.universitySelected[key].selected = value;
   }
});
```